# How to store data as array in getStringList(Shared Preference) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-sharedpreference

I am trying to store the array of documentId when the user click's on the screen. I tried to write and load the data using SharedPreference but it is stored as a string, not as an array.

MyCode:

```
_writedata() async{
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final key = 'my_key';
      prefs.setStringList(key, [docId]);
    }

_loadData() async{
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final key = 'my_key';
      final value = prefs.getStringList(key) ?? [];
      print('load data: $value');
    }
```

My output:

```
I/flutter (17292): load data: [9koh2fe2T4FydH2xoqzo]
I/flutter (17292): load data: [aV58m2nZsHtCtGafidh2]
I/flutter (17292): load data: [60Q9uduXR5sqMww1i58D]
I/flutter (17292): load data: [EmrgSlHOGDUHqzDFo4vm]
I/flutter (17292): load data: [D5mJi5Tt6p8GKP9OyE8r]
```

Can someone please guide me on how to store this in the array format by avoiding duplicate values?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mistaken about what `setStringList` does. All it does is saving the list you give to it. It does not add to an existing list, or check contents of the lists.

If you want a specific logic, like adding to the list or removing duplicates, you need to *get* the list, manipulate the list as you see fit and then *set* this list.